# InteropBitmap to BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage, bitmapsource, interopbitmapimage

I'm trying to Convert a `Bitmap (SystemIcons.Question)` to a `BitmapImage` so I can use it in a WPF Image control.

I have the following method to convert it to a `BitmapSource`, but it returns an `InteropBitmapImage`, now the problem is how to convert it to a `BitmapImage`.  A direct cast does not seem to work.

Does anybody know how to do it?

CODE:

```
 public BitmapSource ConvertToBitmapSource()
        {
            int width = SystemIcons.Question.Width;
            int height = SystemIcons.Question.Height;
            object a = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(SystemIcons.Question.ToBitmap().GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromWidthAndHeight(width, height));

            return (BitmapSource)a;
        }
```

property to return BitmapImage: (Bound to my Image Control)

```
public BitmapImage QuestionIcon
        {
            get
            {
                return  (BitmapImage)ConvertToBitmapSource();
            }
        }
```

Comment: InteropBitmapImage inherits from ImageSource, so you can use it in an Image control. Why do you need it to be a BitmapImage ?

Comment: @Thomas, correct! I solved it without needing to do the conversion! :) Put your comment as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`InteropBitmapImage` inherits from `ImageSource`, so you can use it directly in an `Image` control. You don't need it to be a `BitmapImage`.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use:

```
    public BitmapImage QuestionIcon
    {
        get
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                System.Drawing.Bitmap dImg = SystemIcons.ToBitmap();
                dImg.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                ms.Position = 0;
                System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bImg = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                bImg.BeginInit();
                bImg.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
                bImg.EndInit();
                return bImg;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage QuestionIcon
{
    get
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            System.Drawing.Bitmap dImg = SystemIcons.ToBitmap();
            dImg.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            ms.Position = 0;
            var bImg = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
            bImg.BeginInit();
            bImg.StreamSource = ms;
            bImg.EndInit();
            return bImg;
        }
    }
}
```