# WPF: Image Source is System.Windows.Interop.InteropBitmap

Tags: wpf, image, c#-4.0, interopbitmapimage

How to set the Source of System.Windows.Controls.Image if the Source is a type of System.Windows.Interop.InteropBitmap?
InteropBitmap info below:

```
{System.Windows.Interop.InteropBitmap}
[System.Windows.Interop.InteropBitmap]: {System.Windows.Interop.InteropBitmap}
base {System.Windows.Media.ImageSource}: {System.Windows.Interop.InteropBitmap}
DpiX: 96.0
DpiY: 96.0
Format: {Bgra32}
Height: 851.0
IsDownloading: false
Metadata: null
Palette: null
PixelHeight: 851
PixelWidth: 900
Width: 900.0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `InteropBitmap` inherits from `ImageSource` already.  You should be able to do `myImage.Source = myInteropbitmap;` ?

Ref:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.interopbitmap.aspx

[InteropBitmap to BitmapImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440267/interopbitmap-to-bitmapimage)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source.aspx