# How can I get a bitmap from the clipboard to show in a WPF list control

Tags: wpf

I have an image in a the clipboard ( a bitmap ) which I am pulling from the clipboard as follows

```
     datObj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();  
     InteropBitmap pdfBitmap = datObj.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap) as InteropBitmap;
```

How do I get this pdfBitmap to show up in a WPF listbox. THw WpfListBox looks so..

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Pages}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Margin="10" Source="{Binding Path=UriSource}"></Image>               
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and the binding is to an

```
private ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> pages = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
```

I want to first scale the interopbitmap ( something akin to the getthumbnailimage() ) and then I need to somehow turn the interopbitmap into a BitmapImage .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to convert `InteropBitmap` to a `BitmapImage`....it's an `ImageSource`, so can be set as the `Source` for the `Image` control.

And in your `ListBox` itemtemplate, you just use "`{Binding}`".

You can then "scale" your bitmap by defining a Width and Height on your Image.

(I assume you have a `Pages` property that you use to access the `pages` field)

```
private ObservableCollection<ImageSource> pages = new ObservableCollection<ImageSource>();

 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Pages}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Margin="10" Source="{Binding}"></Image>               
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

---

However if the above is still not suitable...e.g. if you are trying to reduce the memory footprint of your "bitmaps" by converting to a lower resolution (i.e. your thumbnail size), then you can convert from InteropBitmap to a BitmapImage by "streaming" the data out, so it can be "read" by the WPF based BitmapImage.

- [InteropBitmap to BitmapImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440267/interopbitmap-to-bitmapimage)

If you can get access to the underlying Hbitmap then you might be able to use `CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap` (e.g. by accessing the Clipboard using WIN32 calls instead of the WPF/.Net ones).

- [Is there a good way to convert between BitmapSource and Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284353/is-there-a-good-way-to-convert-between-bitmapsource-and-bitmap)